# plotting a given column name across different data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

All, I have multiple dataframes like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 1, 2],
    ['b', 3, 4],
    ['c', 5, 6]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr1', 'attr2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 2, 3],
    ['b', 4, 5],
    ['c', 6, 7]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr1', 'attr2'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 3, 4],
    ['b', 5, 6],
    ['c', 7, 8]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr1', 'attr2'])
```

each of these dataframes are generated at specific time steps says T=[t1, t2, t3]

I would like to plot, attr1 or attr2 of the diff data frames as function of time T. I would like to do this for 'a', 'b' and 'c' on all the same graph.
[Plot Attr1 VS time for 'a', 'b' and 'c'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfYkS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, first assign a column `T` to each of your dataframes, then concatenate the three. Then, you can `groupby` the `name` column, iterate through each, and plot `T` against `attr1` or `attr2`:

```
dfs = pd.concat([df1.assign(T=1), df2.assign(T=2), df3.assign(T=3)])

for name, data in dfs.groupby('name'):
    plt.plot(data['T'], data['attr2'], label=name)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('attr2')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks sacul. The concat doesnt seem to really do the job or maybe its the kind of plot, the yaxis is no longer monotonic. I mean if in the above you change say the df1,  df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 1, 29],
    ['b', 3, 4],
    ['c', 5, 6]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr1', 'attr2'])

Comment: If it's not monotonic, it sounds like some of your `attr`s are string rather than numeric. Try: `plt.plot(data['T'], pd.to_numeric(data['attr2']), label=name)` in the loop instead.